# Issue with using wildcards in php glob()

Tags: php, ubuntu-14.04, glob

I have a strange situation happening with PHP glob() and wondered if anyone has encountered it. This problem may be too broad for here, but trying anyway.

I'm running the following:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS
Release:        14.04
Codename:       trusty

PHP 5.6.20-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1 (cli) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
with Zend OPcache v7.0.6-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2016, by Zend Technologies
with Xdebug v2.3.3, Copyright (c) 2002-2015, by Derick Rethans
```

My glob function was working before using:

```
$images = glob($path . '/' . $id .'.*');
```

Then it suddenly stopped working. I've not really changed anything on the server or in any other code. These are different things I've tried just to see what would happen

```
$images = glob($path . '/' . $id . '.{jpg,jpeg,png,gif}', GLOB_BRACE); //works
$images = glob($path . '/*.jpg'); // doesn't work 
$images = glob($path . '/*'); // doesn't work
```

Basically, anytime I use the wildcard, no matter the position, the script (ran from a command line) just sits there. No error, no return, nothing. I even tried using GlobIterator with the same results.

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling PHP, created a new directory with some temp files to perform tests, and nothing I do seems get it working again. There are about 1000 files in the directory, so it should take all that long to match (I've let it sit for an hour).

So, wondering if anyone has run into this problem before or perhaps know of a solution? This is mainly out of curiosity because I've already rewritten the code not using glob() in some places that required a wildcard.

**Update 2**
It's doing it again. Hanging when using the wildcard. I ran the below tests:

```
// not working
    var_dump(glob('/vagrant/biospex-2.0/storage/scratch/1-8c6b410c42da62d37e7aabc00a61e258/*'));
    // not working
    var_dump(glob('/vagrant/biospex-2.0/storage/scratch/1-8c6b410c42da62d37e7aabc00a61e258/*.jpg'));
    // not working
    var_dump(glob('/vagrant/biospex-2.0/storage/scratch/1-8c6b410c42da62d37e7aabc00a61e258/*.{jpg,jpeg,gif,png,tif,tiff}', GLOB_BRACE));
    // not working
    var_dump(glob('/vagrant/biospex-2.0/storage/scratch/1-8c6b410c42da62d37e7aabc00a61e258/5715116ac46988ff1a8b4b8f.*'));
    // working
    var_dump(glob('/vagrant/biospex-2.0/storage/scratch/1-8c6b410c42da62d37e7aabc00a61e258/5715116ac46988ff1a8b4b8f.jpg'));
```

**Update 3**
In my directory there are 1100 images. I found when I cut that number down to 712, glob returns the array. Adding one more image, total of 713, makes it hang. The difference in size between the two are 1.62GB and 1.63GB respectively. I tried changing PHP settings but they had no effect.
I added a small txt file to the directory and it still hung up. So not really sure what is happening here.
I should also mention this is using Ubuntu on Virtualbox hosted on a Windows machine with shared folders.
For now, I'm simply going to use an iterator.

Comment: Did you try to output `$path . '/*'` and `$path . '/*.jpg'` to see what it becomes and try to match manually (in `ls` in bash or something)?

Comment: That's very odd. What is `$path`? Is there anything particularly weird about it, like containing an asterisk itself or something?

Comment: all I see that's different is that the ones that don't work, doesn't contain `$id`.

Comment: @MaximKhan-Magomedov - Can you explain this a bit more?

Comment: @Chris - the $path is the full path from root. /vagrant/biospex-2.0/storage/scratch  I also tried simply using /vagrant/test and it didn't work

Comment: @Fred-ii- - The one with the id works mainly due to specifying the search more exactly. However, a simply glob('/*') should return all the directory contents.

Comment: @MaximKhan-Magomedov - I did ran

    ls /vagrant/biospex-2.0/storage/scratch/1-8c6b410c42da62d37e7aabc00a61e258/*

and it listed all the image files in the directory

Comment: I just tried the original glob function again and now it's working. This is really weird.

Comment: @rbruhn Well done on fixing it. What a weird problem.

Comment: @Chris - It's not working again. Ran some more tests with actual included path above. I may have to resort to simply opening the dir and reading the files instead of using glob()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really a solution but I ended up rebuilding my local dev server from scratch. The glob() function started working after that. So, something must have happened to mess things up.